# A class made in CSS does not affect HTML for some unknown reason

Tags: css, html

this is my very first post here so in advance I offer any apologies if my post lacks certain required information that is needed to solve the problem; :)

I made a simple class in CSS:

```
.right{
    text-align: right;
}
```

And wanted it to affect my data in HTML:

```
<th class="right">Altitude</th>
```

But unfortunately there are no changes resulting from this class.
In the specific HTML file I made a correct reference to the proper css file:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="journal.css">
```

Any ideas on the cause of all this? My IDE, Netbeans : 'Class 'right' not found.'

EDIT: Adding :

```
.right{
    text-align: right !important;
}
```

Resolved the issue of showing the changes in the browser but my IDE , Netbeans, still doesn't recognise the class though. So this issue remains. Is it even important that it recognises this class?

Comment: can you confirm that the css file is included properly in your script? Did you tried clearing the cache?

Comment: Without context, it's hard to tell. For all we know, the `th` may be too narrow to see the difference.

Comment: Nothing seem to be wrong with the part you posted, so probably problem is from elsewhere. I guess either a syntax error before your .right in css or you're overwriting it afterwards.

Comment: @AnkitPokhrel :Well i can see the right cssfile sitting in the same folder as the htmlfile. So it is in the proper place I'd say. How do you clear the cache?

Comment: @MrLister: What exactly do you mean with context?

Comment: @Samurai: .right is standing as last one on the CSSfile

Comment: Adding `!important` is seldom a solution in itself. In your case, I am 90% sure that you shouldn't use `!important`, but properly debug your CSS selectors.

Comment: I have answered on your question ??

Comment: @BURNS I just meant there were things we couldn't see that could affect the result. As an example, you didn't post other HTML, so it could just as well have been that the table only contained the single `th` cell. That's what I meant. Anyway, the others are right about `!important`: you shouldn't use it as a solution. You can use it as a _debugging tool_: if including it solves things, you have a style rule somewhere that you really don't want. Find that rule and adjust it to your needs; that's the real solution!

Comment: @Gorostas: Yes ,but for some reason I couldnt reply on your post. I think this has smthg to do with my reputation aound here ,which is 8 only now. Not sure though.  Thx :)

Comment: @MrLister:Ill keep it in mind. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that the CSS file is included properly. You can check this using the *Inspect Element* option in Chrome browser on the TH element. If you see that the *right* class is applied, then try to add the !important as said above and see if that helps. Using inspect element, you will see what CSS gets applied and also if the rule gets ignored or not.

Comment: Great ,the important helped and Chrome recognised the .right class. :) But Netbeans still says it doesnt find this class.
Does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

Try add

```
.right{
    text-align: right !important;
}
```